# Maximum precision on very large numbers

Tags: python, division, largenumber

When I try to divide 696 252 / 17 500 423 I always get 0.0.
Is there a way to increase the precision of such divisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert either of the numbers to float with [`float`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) function, like this

```
print float(696252) / 17500423  # 0.0397848669144
```

Answer (score 1):

you must be using python2, you'll need:

```
696252 / 17500423.
                 ^ a decimal point
```

In python3, '/' is float division automatically, while in python2 it's integer division. To be consistent, use `1.0 * a / b` when doing float division.